# FSK technique to superpose the digital communication on top of 4–20 mA signals

Tags: digital-communications, frequency, analog-to-digital, fsk, digital-to-analog

I start a working with HART devices and I really try to understand how digital data is transferred trough 4-20ma current loop.
I start read this article: https://instrumentationtools.com/hart-communication-tutorial-part-1/ and one paragraph said this:
"The HART protocol makes use of the FSK technique to superpose the digital communication on top of 4–20 mA signals. The digital FSK signal is phase continuous and has a 0.5 mA amplitude having two different frequencies, 1200 Hz and 2200 Hz, representing binary 1 and 0, respectively. Since the average DC value of a sine wave over a time period is zero, the FSK signal does not add any DC component on the 4–20 mA analog signal."
I understand that the digital data is superpose on top of 4-20mA, but what I don't understand is if that analog signal "vibrate" to different frequency to produce digital communication data, or is another signal (the "digital" one) beside that, and if it is, how can they don't interact?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. There are two frequency "symbols" used to distinguish a digital "0" from a digital "1". When you want to send a digital "0" the higher frequency is imposed on the analog signal. When you want to send a digital "1" the lower frequency is imposed. Longer term., averaged over many bits, it doesn't shift the analog signal since it averages to zero. But shorter term we can distinguish between 0 and 1 by detecting the higher or lower frequency using a frequency discriminator. What is your question then?

Comment: Cross post, already answered here : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/521335/frequency-key-shift-technique-to-superpose-the-digital-communication-on-top-of-4